# How can I place a UITextView into a UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, uitextview, uialertview, jailbreak

How can I put a `UITextView` in an `UIAlertView`?

Also, I would like this `UITextView` to mirror a text file at `/var/mobile/file.txt`.  How can I make it so that anything that is changed in the `UITextview` would be written to the `file.txt`?

Comment: I like how the title matches the text perfectly, good job!

Answer (score 0):

You can take textView as an instance  variable for later access. add textview as subview in alertview. when alert dismissed get the text of textview and write to that file by using [writeToPath atomic] method. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this before show your alert:

```
UITextView *yourtextview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 90, 260, 50)]; 
[youralert addSubview:yourtextview];
```

Comment: Thanks rafa, even though I already looked at some code that explained it for me.

Comment: I think this is no longer the case in iOS 7?

Answer (score -1):

Yes I actually understand. I did something like that.

So its:

UIAlertView *lol
UITextView *lolTwo
...
[lol addSubview:lolTwo];